# Protocolo Open Graph de Facebook ¿Como hacer que la imagen se muestre completa?

Tags: opengraph

Cuando comparto en Facebook una publicación de mi sitio web muchas veces la imagen de la miniatura se muestra pequeña y otras veces se muestra en pantalla completa. Lo que yo quiero en realidad es que se muestre siempre con la pantalla completa, no me gusta que se muestre de esta forma

[image: Protocolo Open Graph de Facebook]

Yo quiero que la imagen siempre se muestre completa abarcando toda la publicación pero no se como conseguirlo. Hay artículos en mi blog que cuando los comparto en Facebook se muestran como yo quiero, en cambio la mayoría se muestran con la imagen pequeña que es como a mi no me gusta.

### Código que estoy usando actualmente de Open Graph

```html
    <!-- Redes Sociales -->
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@Thecanario">
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Thecanario">
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?=$post['title']?>">
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?=$post['description_post']?>">
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?=$url?>/img/<?=$post['miniatura']?>">
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?=$url?>/article/<?=$post['id_post']?>/<?=clearUrl($post['title'])?>">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
```

Comment: Esto es más una pregunta de soporte de facebook y de su API especificamente que un problema general de programación... no estoy muy seguro pero imagino que tendrán algún tipo de sistema de soporte? No digo que la pregunta esté mal, simplemente que si tienen sitio de soporte seguro que podrán ayudarte mucho más fácil que nosotros

Comment: La verdad es que mi pregunta esta relacionada a la programación **frontend** y estoy seguro que más de un programador tiene los mismos problemas que yo en este momento y otros ya saben como resolverlos y me pueden ayudar a mi en caso de toparse con mi pregunta.

Comment: Y no te digo que no, pero tu duda es específica del producto de Facebook... solo digo que en el *Developer Community Forum* de facebook seguro que no hay *alguien* con el mismo problema, seguro que hay *docenas* de personas que usan eso en este mismo momento... No estoy atacándote, ni diciéndote nada malo... te estoy diciendo que si aquí tardas un mes en encontrar respuesta, allí tardarías 24h, no sé si me explico. Por cierto, la pregunta tendría más posibilidades de ser encontrada si usases los TAG correctos y no un HTML genérico...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto sucede porque no le has dicho a **Facebook** ancho y la altura de tu imagen. Existen muchos sitios web donde [pueden aprender](https://ogp.me/) sobre las etiquetas meta de **Open Graph** y ajustar a tus necesidades los enlaces que comparten tus usuarios o tu. Te recomiendo que le brindes cuanto más datos posible a Facebook.

En este caso, debes de especificarle a Facebook que tu imagen tiene un tamaño superior al mínimo para agregarle la imagen con descripción.

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="627"/>
```

Para no desviarme mucho, con esas dos líneas de código le estas diciendo a Facebook que tu imágenes tiene un ancho de *1200 px* y una altura de *627 px* y siempre que se publique un enlace tuyo en facebook, aparecerá la imagen grande con el titulo sin la descripción. Ahora bien, tengo para decirte que aunque coloques este código junto que en que ya tienes, las publicaciones antiguas no van a funcional, solo funcionanará con los artículos nuevos que hayas creado.

Por ejemplo, si publicas un articulo en tu sitio web hablando de los animales, cuando compartas ese enlace de ese articulo en Facebook va a aparecer con la imagen grande, pero los artículos antiguos no van a aparecer con la imagen grande.

De todos modos, recuerda visitar el enlace que te deje, donde aprenderás mucho sobre Open Graph.

Comment: para refrescar el cache hay una herramienta https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/batch/